# Does a timeout exception ack a task with acks_late?

Tags: timeout, celery

If I have a celery task with `acks_late=True`, and that task raises either a hard or soft timeout exception, is the task acked and removed from the queue, or is it retried? The documentation for [`acks_late`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.acks_late) doesn't mention it either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Should I use retry or acks_late](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry),

> Task.retry is used to retry tasks, notably for expected errors that is catchable with the try: block. The AMQP transaction is not used for these errors: **if the task raises an exception it is still acknowledged!**

Since SoftTimeLimitExceeded is an exception, it stands to reason that it does ack the message and removes it from the queue.

Comment: Yep, the task should capture the exception, and queue another instance of itself to run again.